# Supporting multiple development boards under VS2010 for .NET Micro Framework projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

I'm working on a project using .NET MF and a Fez Panda II board.  While I probably don't need to support any other .NET MF-compatible boards, I thought it would be nice to try to write my code to support them as well.  Fez and Netduino boards have their own assemblies that you have to reference in order to get access to certain peripherals, so I wanted to abstract those details and only build board-specific assemblies by using the Configuration Manager.

The problem is that I've gone into the Configuration Manager and have created a new solution platform, but then my projects aren't able to select this platform -- only "Any CPU" remains available.

Is there another way to approach this issue of supporting different pieces of hardware?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Microframework is an abstraction layer over the hardware, so you shouldn't have to specify the CPU. The porting of the Micro Framework handles the CPU specific portion of the framework, so the changes are isolated to the referenced assemblies primarily 'mscorlib'. Most of the other Microframework assemblies are visible using any of the available reflection utilities.

Comment: This is not completely true.  In some cases, I definitely agree with you, like with SerialPort and OutputPort.  But for the Fez Panda II, you have to reference their own library for things like AnalogIn.  That is the functionality I am trying to abstract, not the other things that are already part of the core framework.